# how do I mimic the terminal path when making a system call in MATLAB on a mac

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to automate mac terminal calls in MATLAB. In my specific use case I used brew to install cmake but in MATLAB cmake isn't recognized `[~,result] = system('cmake ..');` returns `zsh:1: command not found: cmake`

Using the following I am pretty sure I could update the path so that cmake is recognized.
[(Mac,Matlab,bash) Changing the PATH of bash in Matlab for system commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084154/mac-matlab-bash-changing-the-path-of-bash-in-matlab-for-system-commands)

However, I was wondering if there was a generic way of mimicking the path that the terminal is seeing.

In particular when I run `env` in the terminal and in MATLAB using `[~,result] = system('env');` the path variables are different and I'm wondering why that is and how to ensure they align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start MATLAB from its icon on macOS, you never ran the login shell startup files, so most of your configuration is not loaded. That is, anything configured in `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zshrc`, etc. is not seen by MATLAB. Unlike other Unixes, macOS doesn’t start a login shell when you log on. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/263997) for the differences between a login shell and a non-login shell.

One way around this is to launch MATLAB from a terminal window. Another way is to manually load the zsh configuration before running your shell command.

A cleaner solution is to avoid `~/.zprofile` (loaded for login shells) and `~/.zshrc` (loaded for interactive shells), and instead put your configuration in `~/.zshenv` (loaded for all shells, including the one started by MATLAB for `system()` or `!`).

In particular, Homebrew adds a line

```bash
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

to your `~/.zprofile` file. Moving this line to `~/.zshenv` and restarting MATLAB should add the Homebrew configuration to shells started from within MATLAB.

Comment: Makes sense although I dislike needing to edit these files. After reading about this my inclination is to source `~/.zprofile` and get the resulting path `[~,result] = system('. ~/.zprofile; echo $PATH')` and update the environment accordingly `setenv('PATH', getenv('PATH')+"<new_stuff>")` with a little bit more code needed in the middle there to determine `new stuff`. This could presumably be done once on startup. Thoughts? This of course seems to omit the complexity of all the other profiles that could be loaded ...

Comment: @Jimbo There could be other relevant variables declared. But in general it would be elegant to somehow configure future shells on starting MATLAB (`startup.m`). But anyway, `.zshenv` is meant to define environment variables, so defining your path in there is the “right” thing to do.